# Touch mapped incorrectly to screen (Redmi Note 12 4G)

Tags: screen, xiaomi, broken-screen, touchscreen, redmi

I recently replaced the screen on my Xiaomi Redmi Note 12 4G after the original one was damaged for an Amoled one sold on Aliexpress. At first (that is after connecting the battery for the first time), the screen works fine, but after rebooting it, the screen (which btw has 1080x2400) seems to  map the press to a top left rectangle of about 130x300 (so if I touch the bottom right corner it will show me pressing 130x300, I checked using the trace tool). The screen part works perfectly, and using a mirror tool with the computer, the phone does recognise touch on the rest on the screen, but only virtually. If I disconnect the battery and connect it again (or reboot using adb) the screen works fine.

I was hoping I could use some adb command or something of the sort to recalibrate the touchscreen or change the size of the area it recognise.

Thanks in advance for all responses